# Can C# #if directives detect the installation of specific dependencies?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use preprocessor directives to hide code that has an optional dependency?

I want to include some functionality in some code *if the solution has a certain Nuget package installed*. If they don't, no harm, no foul -- that specific functionality is just not available.

Something like:

```
#if SuperCoolNugetPackageIsInstalled

public void DoTheSuperCoolThing()
{
  // Coolness happens here... 
}

#endif
```

I could do this at runtime, but it still wouldn't be able to compile.

(For the record, I would clearly document this.)

Comment: Sure you don't want to use something like `#if`?

Comment: What's the use case? Not using regions, but I've seen libraries that activate certain functionality via reflection when they detect certain assemblies are present. That way they don't have to take a direct dependency on yet another library. Think - taking advantage of the logging library present in an app from a library that you maintain. For example, [LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog).

Comment: @Progman Yes. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @mason But how does that compile?

Comment: Because it's loading the assemblies at runtime via reflection and invoking the functionality then. I linked you to the source code, you're more than welcome to look through and see how it works. You still haven't described your use case, so I don't really know if that's a fitting solution.

Comment: Actually after further inspection, looks like LibLog just copies the code from those other libraries and ships it. But there's nothing preventing you from doing as a I described: using reflection to detect if various assemblies are loaded, then invoking their functionality if they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, provided the NuGet package is specifically crafted for it and consumers of the package isn't too old. [Starting with NuGet 2.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.5#automatic-import-of-msbuild-targets-and-props-files), NuGet packages can contain a `build\` directory with MSBuild property and target files which will automatically be imported into consuming MSBuild projects.

So let's say I'm making a package, `MyFakeNuGetPackage`, using the ["convention-based working directory" method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory). To my working directory, I add a `build\MyFakeNuGetPackage.targets` file with the contents:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_FAKE_IMPORTED</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I use `.targets`, not `.props`, so it is imported after any existing `DefineConstants` in the consuming project, thus appending my constant to any already-defined constants.

Then, in the consuming project, I can have code like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
#if MY_FAKE_IMPORTED
    MyFakeNuGetPackage.MyCoolAPI.CallMe();
#endif
}
```

If the project containing this code references `MyFakeNuGetPackage`, then the API will be called. Otherwise, this code is a no-op.

Comment: This seems complicated, and I don't know if I'll do it, but you have effectively answered my question, so thank you.